# [Jxls]Why SetFunction method cannot be found?

Tags: spring-boot, jxls

I had seen so many code examples in Internet about **Custom Function** in the Jxls.
For example:

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.createTransformer(is, os);
...
JexlExpressionEvaluator evaluator = (JexlExpressionEvaluator) transformer.getTransformationConfig().getExpressionEvaluator();
Map<String, Object> functionMap = new HashMap<>();
functionMap.put("demo", new JexlCustomFunctionDemo());
evaluator.getJexlEngine().setFunctions(functionMap);
```

However,The Demo that its demo-project says:

```
AreaBuilder areaBuilder = new XlsCommentAreaBuilder(transformer);
                List<Area> xlsAreaList = areaBuilder.build();
                Area xlsArea = xlsAreaList.get(0);
                Context context = new Context();
                context.putVar("x", 5);
                context.putVar("y", 10);
                JexlExpressionEvaluator evaluator = (JexlExpressionEvaluator) transformer.getTransformationConfig().getExpressionEvaluator();
                Map<String, Object> functionMap = new HashMap<>();
                functionMap.put("demo", new JexlCustomFunctionDemo());
//                evaluator.getJexlEngine().setFunctions(functionMap);  
                xlsArea.applyAt(new CellRef("Sheet1!A1"), context);
                transformer.write();
```

As you can see, the key sentence was disabled and I have tried the `2.6.0` edition, it exactly doesn't support the `setFunction`

And I tried to use `2.4.3` edition but when I put the `jxls` and `jxls-poi` together in `build.gradle` , it imported `2.6.0` automatically.

#### I wonder

How I can use the **Custom Function** in `Jxls` like the first code segement?

### Thanks for your help!

Here is my gradle file

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/release/' }
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot-local" }
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone-local" }
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-release-local" }
    maven { url "http://maven.jeecg.org/nexus/" }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':common-base')
    compile project(':common-redis')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}")
    compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjrt', version: '1.8.9'
    compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjweaver', version: '1.8.9'
    compile 'org.freemarker:freemarker:2.3.23'
    compile 'org.jxls:jxls:2.4.3'
    compile 'org.jxls:jxls-poi:1.0.9'
//    compile 'org.jxls:jxls-jexcel:1.0.6'
    //swagger2.5.0 ApiImplicitParam的dataType不支持自定义类
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.7.0'
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.7.0'
    compile 'io.springfox:springfox-bean-validators:2.7.0'
    compile group: 'org.bouncycastle', name: 'com.springsource.org.bouncycastle.jce', version: '1.39.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '3.14-beta1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '3.17'
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-scratchpad', version: '3.17'
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml-schemas', version: '3.17'
    compile "com.xuxueli:xxl-job-core:2.1.0"    // 调度中心xxl-job
    compile group: 'commons-lang', name: 'commons-lang', version: '2.6'
    compile group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'itextpdf', version: '5.5.13'
    compile group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'itext-asian', version: '5.2.0'
    compile group: 'com.github.tobato', name: 'fastdfs-client', version: '1.25.2-RELEASE'
    //属性拷贝dozer/cglib
    compile('net.sf.dozer:dozer:5.5.1')
    compile('cglib:cglib:3.2.8')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [JexlCustomFunctionDemo.java](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls/src/master/jxls-examples/src/main/java/org/jxls/demo/JexlCustomFunctionDemo.java) from [jxls-examples](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls/src/master/jxls-examples/) on `master` branch has the correct code which should work fine

```
            Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.createTransformer(is, os);
            AreaBuilder areaBuilder = new XlsCommentAreaBuilder(transformer);
            List<Area> xlsAreaList = areaBuilder.build();
            Area xlsArea = xlsAreaList.get(0);
            Context context = new Context();
            context.putVar("x", 5);
            context.putVar("y", 10);
            JexlExpressionEvaluator evaluator = (JexlExpressionEvaluator) transformer.getTransformationConfig().getExpressionEvaluator();
            Map<String, Object> functionMap = new HashMap<>();
            functionMap.put("demo", new JexlCustomFunctionDemo());
            JexlEngine customJexlEngine = new JexlBuilder().namespaces(functionMap).create();
            evaluator.setJexlEngine(customJexlEngine);
            xlsArea.applyAt(new CellRef("Sheet1!A1"), context);
            transformer.write();
```

The code in the old [jxls-demo](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls-demo/src/master/) repo is deprecated and no longer supported.